# NSInvalidArgumentException exception when adding image to imageView iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

.H files

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) LAClaimReport *claimReport;
```

.M file

```
@interface LACreateReportViewController ()
{
    NSArray *_thumbnails;
    LAPhotoThumb *_lastSelectedPhoto;
}

_thumbnails = _claimReport.photos.allObjects;
    if (_thumbnails.count >0)
    {
        _photosCaption.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:46/255.0 blue:91/255.0 alpha:1];

        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 1838, 300, 600)];
         NSLog(@"image:%@" , _thumbnails[0]);
        [image setImage:(UIImage *) _thumbnails[0]]; // exception here.

}
```

**NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LAPhoto size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa76b720'**

Photos is a column in the class file of `LAClaimReport`. What am i missing in regards to size here? pls guide.

Comment: make sure that you have UIImage class objects in _thumbnails Array, I Think you have LAPhoto type objects in that array

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman  UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 1838, 300, 600)];
         NSLog(@"image:%@" , _thumbnails[0]);
        UIImage *images = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:_thumbnails
                           [0]];
        [image setImage:images]; is this fine?

Answer (score 1):

`_thumbnails` doesn't contain `UIImage` instances, it contains some other type of object. Enough information isn't included to tell what kind of objects it contains however.

`size` is a method on `UIImage` that is used by the image view to determine how to display the image, and whatever object is actually in `_thumbnails` doesn't implement that method.

Your `NSLog(@"image:%@" , _thumbnails[0]);` should list the class type that you're trying to use as an image.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have UIImage class objects in _thumbnails Array, I Think you have LAPhoto type objects in that array

```
id arrContent=_thumbnails[0];
    if ([arrContent isKindOfClass:[LAPhoto Class]])
    {
        //read LAPhoto class and find a way to get the UIImage from LAPhoto Object
    }
    else if ([arrContent isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
    {
        [image setImage:(UIImage *) _thumbnails[0]];
    }
```